# I want to show all Course Names According To Department It Shows Error "The data types text and nvarchar are incompatible in the equal to operator."

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms

I want to show all Course Names According To Department It Shows Error:

> The data types text  and nvarchar are incompatible in the equal to operator.

Here Is My Code:

```cs
    void GetCoursesNames()
    {
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    conn.Open();
    cmd.Connection = conn;
    cmd.CommandText = " select Course_Name from Course Where Department = @Department";
    //cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Department", DepttextBox.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Department", (object)DepttextBox.Text ?? DBNull.Value);
    SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    while (dr.Read())
    {
    Subj_comboBox.Items.Add(dr["Course_Name"]);
    }
    conn.Close();
```

Comment: The error is telling you the problem here. Of course, the *real* question is why are you *still* using the `text` data type, it's been deprecated for **16 years**.

Comment: Suggested reading: [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/), [it's evil](https://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/).

Comment: Larnu What data type i used for it

Comment: @NomanUllah: `nvarchar` seems reasonable.

Comment: See the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/ntext-text-and-image-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15), @NomanUllah . There's a box starting with "**IMPORTANT!**" that tells you what you should be using.

Comment: In truth, why is `Department` defined as needing up to **2 billion** characters? Surely the length  of the values would be significantly smaller, no? If they *do* you need to be storing such large data, then the column is a poor choice for a `WHERE` clause, as SQL Server is going to perform awful with a clause that effectively resolves to `WHERE {50,000 character string} = {50,000 character string}`

Comment: You should also have `using` blocks for your connection, command and reader. The connection should *not* be cached, dispose immediately